# C error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: arrays, c, bit, lvalue, insertion

I get this error in C: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

```
    void bfInsertion(BloomFilter* bloomFilter,const char* elem,int elemLen)
{
    int i = 1;

    while (i <= elem)
    {
        elem[i] = 1;    
        i += 1;
    }

    return elem;
}
```

I understood that the problem it's about the left side of `elem[i] = 1;` but I couldn't understand how to do it correctly.
Elem is an array of byte and I want to put 1 on the i-th bit.

This is the pseudo-code:

```
1. i ←1;
2. while i ≤ k do
3. b[hi (delta)] ← 1;
4. i ← i + 1;
```

PS. I can only modify what's inside the function, not what i pass to it

Comment: remove the word `const`, which means **constant**. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

`elem` is a pointer to `const char`. So you can not modify it. Just make it pointer to char only.

Comment: I can't. I can only modify what's inside the function, not what I pass to it!

Comment: In that case, I must say you are not supposed to change anything in the `elem` variable. I think you have to clarify the logic a bit. Can you explain the pseudo-code you have provided?

Answer (score 0):

The elem array is declared `const` and so cannot be modified. To modify it you would need to remove the `const` keyword.

You can then use pointer arithmetic to change your value:

```
*(elem + i) = a value
```

Though remember that things are numbered from zero in C in general so for the ith
value this would be

```
*(elem + i - 1) = a value
```